# How to make a radio button when a checkbox button clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make a radio button when a checkbox button is clicked? And also, how to erase the radio button, when the checkbox is unchecked?

```
if($("input[type=checkbox]").is(':checked')==true) {
  var val = this.value;
  var dataSplit = val.split("_");
  var result = '<div id="div'+dataSplit[0]+'"><input type="radio" class="choosen"
    name="rdb_'+val+'" value="'+val+'" id="'+dataSplit[0]+
    '" /><label class="'+dataSplit[0]+'">'+dataSplit[1]+'</label><br /></div>';
  $("#result").append(result);
}else if ($("input[type=checkbox]").is(':checked')==false){
  var val1 = this.value;
  var dataSplit1 = val1.split("_");
  $('#div'+dataSplit1[0]).parent.remove();
}
```

The code works when I check the checkbox, but it doesn't work when I uncheck the checkbox. When I uncheck, the radio button is still added.

NB: Try to check 2/3 checkboxes, and uncheck them.

Comment: can you provide demo on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: sorry, i'm a newbie, i donw know how to provide  on jsfiddle - vins and vince lowe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably bind it to the change event of the checkbox, and just do:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function() {
    var val = this.value;
    var dataSplit = val.split("_");
    if (this.checked) {
        var result = '<div id="div'+dataSplit[0]+'"><input type="radio" class="choosen" name="rdb_'+val+'" value="'+val+'" id="'+dataSplit[0]+'" /><label class="'+dataSplit[0]+'">'+dataSplit[1]+'</label><br /></div>';
        $("#result").append(result);
    }else{
        $('#div'+dataSplit[0]).remove();
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RV4Fg/)

Comment: Eventually? I never edited my answer, but you did, but I don't really care!

Comment: What the frack are you talking about? I posted right after you and never edited my answer, your answer had no code, and just pointed out the missing quotes on parent, then a few minutes after I posted you edited your answer and added code very similar to mine. I don't know if you noticed my answer or not, but saying it's just like yours and that I "came late to the party" is just rubbish, god I hate trolls.

Comment: Apologies. Were mainly irritated by others here - including a vendetta downvote. I'll remove my comments

Comment: I still will argue that onclick is better than onchange since in some browsers, onchange will not trigger until the object loses focus.

Comment: Yes, but onclick will not work if you tab and use spacebar to change it.

Comment: ah - that is an interesting twist. +1

Comment: Actually, seems in IE change fires when the checkbox loses focus. So if you tab to it, hit space a few times and tab out, you'll only get one onchange event, but several onclick events, binding to both events won't work without some more code to make sure it does'nt fire twice, so I guess it's up to the OP the figure out what works for him/her? And spacebar does fire the onclick event, so that's probably the better option of the two.

Answer (score 1):

Errors:

- `parent().remove()` not `parent.remove()` but why remove the parent of the div instead of the div?
- `dataSplit1` instead of `dataSplit`

Notice I use *click* instead of *change* since some browsers will not trigger the event until the object loses focus when the change event is used - however as adeneo pointed out in a comment, there may be a tab/spacebar trigger that does not trigger the click...

[TESTING](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/6MEDu/) that hypothesis in FX on OSX sees that onclick and onchange are triggered by either spacebar or mouse

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
  var val = this.value;
  var dataSplit = val.split("_");
  if (this.checked) {
    var result = '<div id="div'+dataSplit[0]+'"><input type="radio" class="choosen"
      name="rdb_'+val+'" value="'+val+'" id="'+dataSplit[0]+
      '" /><label for="'+dataSplit[0]+'" class="'+dataSplit[0]+'">'+dataSplit[1]+'</label><br /></div>';
    $("#result").append(result);
  }
  else {
    $('#div'+dataSplit[0]).remove();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy, I'll outline the steps for you  - [Fiddle - Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/kVYy2/)

```
//Get all checkboxes you want to monitor
var myCheckBoxesContainer = $('.checkboxes_container');

//Monitor the change event of these checkboxes
myCheckBoxesContainer.on('change', '.checkboxes', function(){
    var self = $(this), checked = self.is(':checked'), dataSplit = self.val().split('_');

    //code to create radio button
    if(checked){ 
        /* code goes here */ 
        var result = '<div id="div'+dataSplit[0]+'"><input type="radio" class="choosen" name="rdb_'+val+'" value="'+val+'" id="'+dataSplit[0]+'" /><label class="'+dataSplit[0]+'">'+dataSplit[1]+'</label><br /></div>';
        $("#result").append(result);
    }

    //code to delete the radio button
    else{ 
        /* delete code goes here */ 
        $('#div' + dataSplit[0]).remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify it:

```
if($("input[type=checkbox]").is(':checked')==true) {
  var val = this.value;
  var dataSplit = val.split("_");
  var result = '<div id="div'+dataSplit[0]+'"><input type="radio" class="choosen"
    name="rdb_'+val+'" value="'+val+'" id="'+dataSplit[0]+
    '" /><label class="'+dataSplit[0]+'">'+dataSplit[1]+'</label><br /></div>';
  $("#result").append(result);
} else { // Just use else here
  var val1 = this.value;
  var dataSplit1 = val1.split("_");
  // $('#div'+dataSplit1[0]).parent.remove(); should 

  $('#div'+dataSplit1[0]).remove(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "else if" try only "else" as a checkbox can be only checked on unchecked.

```
if($("input[type=checkbox]").is(':checked')==true) 
{
  var val = this.value;
  var dataSplit = val.split("_");
  var result = '<div id="div'+dataSplit[0]+'"><input type="radio" class="choosen"
    name="rdb_'+val+'" value="'+val+'" id="'+dataSplit[0]+
    '" /><label class="'+dataSplit[0]+'">'+dataSplit[1]+'</label><br /></div>';
  $("#result").append(result);
}
else
{
  var val1 = this.value;
  var dataSplit1 = val1.split("_");
  $('#div'+dataSplit[0]).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`is(':checked')` returns a boolean value `true` or `false`, there is no need to compare the returned value with `true` or `false`:

```
if ($("input[type=checkbox]").is(':checked') { // if true
  // ...
} else { // if not true == false
  // ..
}
```

note that there is a typo in your code `parent` should be `parent()`.

Comment: Not the only one. dataSplit1 also